# Encrypting a 160-bit plaintext into a 160 bit ciphertext with a 128-bit Block Cipher

Tags: encryption, aes, block-cipher, format-preserving

So I have a kind of interesting issue. I have a field in my data store which must take exactly 160 bits of information. Some users will choose to make this data encrypted, some won't, so some of those 160 bit fields will be ciphertext some will be plaintext. A boolean will indicate which one the user is using. The important thing here is that I need this field to be exactly 160 bits long. However, a 128-bit cipher will mean I have to put in 256 bits in as plaintext, which is fine, just use a buffer string, but this means that the output is 256 bits when what is stored must be exactly 160 bits. And I can't simply cut off the ciphertext or that would mess up the decryption. So how can I use a 128-bit block cipher like AES (note it MUST be a 128 bit block cipher, I can't change that) to encrypt 160 bits into 160 bits such that it can be decrypted back into the original 128 bits.

Comment: [Counter mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Counter_.28CTR.29) can accomplish this. Note that you **must** choose a distinct initialization vector for each dataset, such as the hash of a serial number or unique ID.

Comment: One approach you could use is to use AES as a stream cipher, for example in CTR mode.  Create a global nonce for use on all records.  Then you can use the Primary Key for that record in the database as your counter.  In this mode, AES is "encrypting" the nonce and counter and XORing the output with the plain text.  So you can do this and just discard the extra AES output without damaging your cipher text.  Stream cipher encryption, like this CTR mode, typically outputs exactly the same length as the input.  I also saw format preserving encryption mentioned.  Have a look at that as well.

Comment: @WDS I would say that the primary key must be the most significant part of your counter. You could also use the 16 byte hash value of the primary key as the initial counter. If you use the primary key directly then you may have overlap between counters.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question even though it is on-topic because [it has also been posted on Computer Science and has been answered there](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/47775/encrypting-a-160-bit-plaintext-into-a-160-bit-ciphertext-with-a-128-bit-block-ci). [Please do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu).

Comment: Google for "ciphertext stealing". You can use then the AES in block mode.